# ¿Como verificar que un String comienza con 55?

Tags: java, android-studio, string

Estoy realizando una aplicación en la que el usuario registra su numero telefónico.

Al dar clic en continuar se verifica que los campos no este vacíos y que tenga una longitud de 10 caracteres pero también quiero verificar que inicie con "55"

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?.

Lo que tengo es:

```
btnGo.setonclicListener(){
...

    String CellphoneObtained = ETCellphoneObteined.getText().toString();


}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)

Comment: Muchas Gracias Bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String#startsWith(prefijo)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))

```
if (CellphoneObtained.startsWith("55"))  {


    // código

}
```